# Find element by xpath and click on it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to load complete list of images on a page. There is a "Show More" button on the page. I want to click it until all the images are loaded.

**HTML:**

```
<li class="show-more-row">
    <button class="show-more-cta bottom-btn ga"data-ga-action="click"data-ga-label="category-see-more:SectionCourses>Show More
        <i class="lyndacon arrow-down"></i>
    </button>
</li>
```

I have to tried to get the element by Xpath. But it keeps on changing every time I click on the button.

Example:

`//*[@id="category-courses"]/li[101]/button` and `//*[@id="category-courses"]/li[151]/button`

I have also tried finding element by class name:

```
while(browser.find_element_by_class_name("show-more-cta bottom-btn ga")):
    moreElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("show-more-cta bottom-btn ga")
    moreElem.click()
```

But it gives error:

> invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Comment: Try just show-more-cta. The error you are getting is coming from the fact that there are spaces in the class name. This indicates that there is a compound class

Comment: You may also want to look into using finding by CSS selector. I believe this lets you deal with the compound class issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use search by relative `XPath` instead of by absolute `XPath` or by `class_name`:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='show-more-cta bottom-btn ga']")
```

or

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='Show More']")
```

Comment: Best way to use cssSelector here as `button.show-more-cta.bottom-btn.ga`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, there can be few reasons to use `CSS selector` instead of `XPath`, but question sounds like `Find element by xpath...`

Answer (score 1):

**Compound/multiple classes cannot be used in a "by class name" locator**. You have to either leave a single class in the locator:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("show-more-cta")
```

Or, use a different strategy, e.g. a CSS selector:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".show-more-cta.bottom-btn.ga")
```

Note that I'd just leave a single "show-more-cta" class - it is a good choice since it brings value and meaning to the locator making it readable. `bottom-btn` and `ga` classes on the other hand don't have any substantial meaning in this case - these classes are layout/design/markup oriented.